# count the number of words between two lines in a text file

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

As the title says I'm wondering if there is an easier way of getting the number of words between two lines in a text file, using text processing tools available on *nix.

For example given a text file is as follows,

```
a bc ae
a b
ae we wke wew
```

countwords between, 1-2 -> 5, 2-3 -> 6.

Comment: Have you tried `wc` (*word count*)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a simple `awk` command:-

```
awk -v start='1' -v end='2' 'NR>=start && NR <=end{sum+=NF}END{print sum}' file
```

For the sample file you have provided:-

```
$ cat file
a bc ae
a b
ae we wke wew

$ awk -v start='1' -v end='2' 'NR>=start && NR <=end{sum+=NF}END{print sum}' file
5

$ awk -v start='2' -v end='3' 'NR>=start && NR <=end{sum+=NF}END{print sum}' file
6

$ awk -v start='1' -v end='3' 'NR>=start && NR <=end{sum+=NF}END{print sum}' file
9
```

The logic is simple:-

1. Use the `start`, `end` variables for specifying the ranges in the file, they are `awk` variables
2. `NR>=start && NR <=end` provides the condition to loop from the lines you need
3. `sum+=NF` does the word count arithmetic. `NF` is a special `awk` variable which counts the number of words de-limited by `IFS`, which in this case is white-space.
4. `END{print sum}` prints the final count.

Worked fine on `GNU Awk 3.1.7`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed` and `wc` like this:

```
sed -n '1,2p' file | wc -w
5
```

and

```
sed -n '2,3p' file | wc -w
6
```